# Can't find nfs-common or nfs-utils in Xubuntu

Tags: mount, xubuntu, fstab, nfs

I'm new to Ubuntu, but not new to Linux.  I've installed Xubuntu 18.04 to check it out, and I'd like to mount some of my NAS shares.  I've added appropriate lines to /etc/fstab, but so far I've been unsuccessful.

On other systems, nfs-common or nfs-utils is required, but so far I haven't been able to find a software manager that will install either one.

Does anyone here know what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you updated software repository lists? (`sudo apt update`) and tried installing with `sudo apt install nfs-common` as it's there. (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nfs-common)  I would then check your sources `apt-cache policy nfs-common` but suspect you've not tried commands, `synaptic` or `aptitude`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  That's what I needed.  Did I mention that I'm new to Ubuntu?  I've learned quite a bit from your reply.

Comment: I have nfs-common but not nfs-utils.  synaptic didn.t help me.

Comment: Some distros provide nfs-common, others provide nfs-utils.  Either one should provide access to nfs shares.